# How can I use django-paypal for paypal adaptive payments?

Tags: django, paypal, django-paypal

I need to use paypal adaptive payments. Is it possible to do that with django-paypal package?

Is there any way to do that? Or I should just use API directly.

Comment: you can use django-paypal package. it works for me

Comment: @doniyor Yeah, I'm using django-paypal, but I don't know how to use it for paypal adaptive payments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

django-paypal doesn't support Adaptive Payments.

Use API directly.